# Rendering nested router view without parent router view - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, nested-routes

Hello community :) My first Q here.
(There were couple of similar questions but they didn't answer my particular code issue and I tried them to apply but without success.)

So I would like to render the child component in nested route without the parent one showing in the view
See the picture at the end --->

```js
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import Routing from "./components/Routings";



export default class Browserrouting extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routing/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the Routing component :

```js
import About from "../views/About";
import HomeBackground from "../views/Background";
import ShelterApp from '../views/ShelterApp';


export default (props) => (
    <div className="flexColumn">
        <div> <ul className="flexRow center">
            <li className="homeLink"><Link className="colorBrown" to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li className="homeLink"><Link className="colorBrown" to="/shelterApp">Shelter App</Link></li>

            <li className="homeLink"><Link className="colorBrown" to="/about">About our site and shelter</Link></li>
        </ul></div>

        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={() => <HomeBackground />} />
            <Route path="/about" component={() => <About />} />
            <Route path="/shelterApp" component={() => <ShelterApp />} />
        </Switch>
    </div>

)
```

And in ShelterApp component I have some text and imported another component which contains the links and nested routes I would like to display without showing the parent component ShelterApp:

```js
class ShelterApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (   
             <div className="flex center">
               
        <div className="card center" style={{ "width": "25em", "height":"25em" }}>
            <div className="card-body textCenter">
                <h5 className="card-title paddingTitle">Welcome to our site</h5>
                <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"> Login or register if it's your first time</h6>
        
            </div>
            <LoginRouting match={this.props.match} />
        </div>
        
        </div>)
    }

}

export default ShelterApp;
```

and the final child componet with the "lowest" routes in hierarchy :

```js
class LoginRouting extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            users: []
        }
    }
    static propTypes = {
        match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    render() {
        const { match, location, history } = this.props;

        return (
            <div >
                <div className="flexRow center">
                    <Button className={" loginRouting"} type={"button"} bootstrapClass={"btn btn-light"} child={<Link to="/shelterApp/login">Login form</Link>} />
                    <Button className={" loginRouting"} type={"button"} bootstrapClass={"btn btn-light"} child={<Link to="/shelterApp/register">Register form</Link>} />
                </div>
                <div>

                    <Route path="/shelterApp/login" render={() => <Login />} />

                    <Route path="/shelterApp/register" render={() => <Register />} />

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default withRouter( LoginRouting)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KwEu.png)

IMAGE with the view : 
I will be thankful for any advises !

Answer (score 0):

On your `ShelterApp` component you can create a new state called `hideInfo`, or something, that tracks if the user clicked on "Login form" or "Register form".

Then you can pass a props to your `<LoginRouting>` component.
When the user clicks on "Login form" or "Register form" you change `this.hideInfo`.

`<LoginRouting 
    onShowForm={() => this.setState({ hideInfo: !hideInfo})}
    match={this.props.match} 
/>`

Comment: thanks Breno for replying, I tried something similiar but i have the feeling I am complicating it a bit :D